# Basic Bootstrap 5 Modal is firing twice

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I have a modal that works in most ways - it changes content based on which image is clicked... but it is firing twice on the backend and for the life of me I can't find out why!!! This was basically taken directly from bootstrap's documentation so I'm not sure where the problem is coming from. While it's not a problem on the front-end it will cause issue moving forward with updating data, running ajax, etc. When the following code is run, the console prints the modalTitle twice. Where am I gong wrong?!?

It's worth it to note that I have another modal on the page, but even when I've commented it out completely it didn't fix the issue and I figured that I'm calling ONLY the modal with `id="moveModal"` so not sure why that would be a problem anyway. Thank you for your help!

**HTML Image that calls modal when clicked**

```
<img data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#moveModal" data-bs-card="{myCardNameHere}" class="viewCard" id="{cardIdHere}" src="{cardImgPathHere}">
```

**HTML Modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="moveModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="moveModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="moveModalLabel">Move</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <form id="moveForm" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="type" value="move">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Move</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script to update title**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var modal = document.getElementById('moveModal')
  modal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = event.relatedTarget
    var card = button.getAttribute('data-bs-card')
    var modalTitle = modal.querySelector('.modal-title')
    modalTitle.textContent = 'Move ' + card
    console.log(modalTitle);
  });
});
```

Comment: I tested your code but the console printed the modal title only one time, as expected.

Comment: I agree with @ths, here is JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yksr953h/

Comment: @ths Crap. I'm even more confused now. I can comment EVERYTHING out but the necessaries and it still happens. *sigh* Thanks for the help guys - I'll keep grinding to see what else I can find.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**
The code itself was just fine (as some pointed out in the comments) - I FINALLY realized that I had included the script file that includes the JS within a loop rather than outside of it as intended, causing the multiple modal fires.

Lesson learned - CHECK YOUR LOOPS!!